# lpsolve - unfeasible solution, but I have example of 1

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve

I'm trying to solve this in LPSolve IDE:

```
/* Objective function */
min: x + y;

/* Variable bounds */
r_1: 2x = 2y;
r_2: x + y = 1.11 x y;
r_3: x >= 1;
r_4: y >= 1;
```

but the response I get is:

```
Model name:  'LPSolver' - run #1
Objective:   Minimize(R0)

SUBMITTED
Model size:        4 constraints,       2 variables,            5 non-zeros.
Sets:                                   0 GUB,                  0 SOS.

Using DUAL simplex for phase 1 and PRIMAL simplex for phase 2.
The primal and dual simplex pricing strategy set to 'Devex'.

The model is INFEASIBLE
lp_solve unsuccessful after 2 iter and a last best value of 1e+030
```

How come this can happen when `x=1.801801802` and `y=1.801801802` are possible solutions here?

Comment: what about this value that I posted -> 1.801801802

Comment: 3.603603604 = 3.603603604

Comment: You have non linear constraints, and this, I guess, is beyond the capacity of a linear solver.

Comment: @nicola any way to make it linear?

Comment: No, it's a constraint, and it say that the product of the two variables must be equal to the sum times a factor. If you change it, you have a different constraint.

Comment: Solvers for these type of non-convex nonlinear problems are readily available (e.g. [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How To Find The Solution**

Let's do some math.

Your problem is:

```
min x+y
s.t. 2x = 2y
     x + y = 1.11 x y
     x >= 1
     y >= 1
```

The first constraint `2x = 2y` can be simplified to `x=y`. We now substitute throughout the problem:

```
min 2*x
s.t. 2*x = 1.11 x^2
     x >= 1
```

And rearrange:

```
min 2*x
s.t. 1.11 x^2-2*x=0
     x >= 1
```

From geometry we know that `1.11 x^2-2*x` makes an upward-opening parabola with a minimum less than zero. Therefore, there are exactly two points. These are given by the quadratic equation: 200/111 and 0.

Only one of these satisfies the second constraint: 200/111.

**Why Can't I Find This Constraint With My Solver**

The easy way out is to say it's because the `x^2` term (`x*y` before the substitution is nonlinear). But it goes a little deeper than that. Nonlinear problems can be *easy* to solve as long as they are *convex*. A [convex problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization) is one whose constraints form a single, contiguous space such that any line drawn between two points in the space stays within the boundaries of the space.

Your problem is not convex. The constraint `1.11 x^2-2*x=0` defines an infinite number of points. No two of these points can be connected by a straight line which stays in the space defined by the constraint because that space is curved. If the constraint were instead `1.11 x^2-2*x<=0` then the space would be convex because all points could be connected with straight lines that stay in its interior.

Nonconvex problems are part of a broader class of problems called [NP-Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness). This means that there is not (and perhaps cannot) be any easy way of solving the problem. We have to be smart.

Solvers that can handle [mixed-integer programming (MIP/MILP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) can solve many non-convex problems efficiently, as can other techniques such as [genetic algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm). But, beneath the hood, these techniques all rely on glorified guess-and-check.

So your solver fails because the problem is nonconvex and your solver is neither smart enough to use MIP to guess-and-check its way to a solution nor smart enough to use the quadratic equation.

**How Then Can I Solve The Problem?**

In this particular instance, we are able to use mathematics to quickly find a solution because, although the problem is nonconvex, it is part of a class of special cases. Deep thinking by mathematicians has given us a simple way of handling this class.

But consider a few generalizations of the problem:

```
(a) a x^3+b x^2+c x+d=0
(b) a x^4+b x^3+c x^2+d x+e =0
(c) a x^5+b x^4+c x^3+d x^2+e x+f=0
```

(a) has three potential solutions which must be checked (exact solutions are [tricky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients)), (b) has four ([trickier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Ferrari%27s_solution)), and (c) has five. The formulas for (a) and (b) are *much* more complex than the quadratic formula and mathematicians have shown that there is [*no* formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) for (c) that can be expressed using "elementary operations". Instead, we have to resort to glorified guess-and-check.

So the techniques we used to solve your problem don't generalize very well. This is what it means to live in the realm of the nonconvex and NP-hard, and it's a good reason to fund research in mathematics, computer science, and related fields.

Comment: Great explanation. Just to nitpick, I'd add that a convex problem requires also a convex objective function and having just a convex set defined by the constraints is not enough.